# Django: Form submission in ajax style without csrf token

Tags: django

I am new to django. Suppose I have a form and I would like to submit a file to the server in ajax.

I notice that the server has HTTP 403 error when I don't specify the csrf token in the post statement (correct behaviour), but somehow the file can still be able to upload to the server...

Here is my sample code:

models.py (include model and form):

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

# Create your models here.
class Dummy(models.Model):
    myfile = models.FileField(upload_to='temp')

class DummyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dummy
        fields = ['myfile',]
```

views.py:

```
# Create your views here.
class TestFormView(View):
def get(self, request):
    form = DummyForm()

    context = { 'form' : form }
    print form
    return render(request, 'testform.html', context)

def post(self, request):
    print request.FILES
    form = DummyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    print form.is_valid()
    print form.errors
    print form.is_bound
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    print Dummy.objects.all().count()
    return render(request, 'testform.html')
```

testform.html:

```
<form id="myForm" action="testform/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
 <input id="id_myfile" type="file" size="60" name="myfile">
 <input type="submit" value="Ajax File Upload">
</form>

<div id="progress">
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="percent">0%</div >
</div>
<br/>

<div id="message"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

var options = {
beforeSend: function()
{
    $("#progress").show();
    //clear everything
    $("#bar").width('0%');
    $("#message").html("");
    $("#percent").html("0%");
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete)
{
    $("#bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
    $("#percent").html(percentComplete+'%');

},
success: function()
{
    $("#bar").width('100%');
    $("#percent").html('100%');

    alert("done!");

},
complete: function(response)
{
    $("#message").html("<font color='green'>"+response.responseText+"</font>");
},
error: function()
{
    $("#message").html("<font color='red'> ERROR: unable to upload files</font>");

}

};

 $("#myForm").ajaxForm(options);

 $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var url = $form.attr('action');

    $.post("testform/", { myfile: $('#myfile').val()});

    return false;

 });

});

</script>
```

Of course if I put the csrf token in the $post function, I get HTTP 200.

My concern is that will this create security hole because it looks like anyone can upload files to the server?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually looks like I added the csrf in the form. I try to take it out and looks like I cannot submit the form so I think I am ok?

Comment: yeah. I guess you are ok. csrf protects you from injection attacks.